# Dы и инструментыs

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

[image]

Comment: Опечатки поправил (должны стать доступны в течении дня). Все изображения будем менять разом в будущем.