# На странице привилегии скриншот на английском языке

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Страница https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во многих местах справки скрины на буржуйском.

Comment: @Suvitruf во чего [нашел](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270/d%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8bs?rq=1#comment529_270). Ждём будущего.