# На странице справки об общих ответах не переведён скриншот

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, изображения

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) не переведён скриншот:

> [image: (.)(.)]

Comment: Привет! "Your Answer" - тоже не переведен вверху :)

Comment: @L.F.C. Привет) Your Answer тоже входит в скрин. Это у меня на скрине в ответе не было его, я заменил скрин.

Comment: Всё, вижу, принято )

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8552/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: Уже было подобное.... Николас сказал ждём будущего)) https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270/d%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8bs?rq=1#comment529_270

Comment: @byVerng спасибо)

Comment: @Suvitruf, вроде бы модераторы имеют какой-то там ограниченный доступ к редактированию страниц справки? Если я правильно помню Волынкина.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ только когда Николай даёт доступ на правку. Одновременно можно дать доступ лишь к нескольким статьям.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik а он не даёт? )

Comment: @αλεχολυτ он после НГ на сайте почти не появляется и редко отвечает.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik хорошо отметил, видимо.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Приветики) Ну вы и доктор Франкенштейн

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю заменить на этот скрин:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хочу заметить, что FHRC (Free Hand Red Cirlce) это "фишечка" сайтов SE. Так что овал я бы поменял на что-то более подходящее.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ т.е. руками нарисовать круг? В оригинале круг зеленого цвета, а не красного. А руками я могу нарисовать, но это будет напоминать лужу - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR3k9.png

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не знаете, откуда пошла эта традиция, рисовать руками круг?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, скиньте шаблон FHRC в векторе, чтобы можно было прифотошопливать на любые скрины :)

Comment: Если посмотреть [англоязычную справку](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), то там вовсе нет картинки. Так что ещё предстоит выяснить откуда появился зелёный. Про FHRC наверное где-то на MSE можно найти.